# Github Actions Pipeline Failure with axe-core/cli -

Tags: github-actions, axe

I'm trying to run axe-core/cli as a Github Action on my pipeline, however I keep getting this error:

"Error: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 121
Current browser version is 120.0.6099.224 with binary path /opt/google/chrome/chrome

Please install a matching version of ChromeDriver and run axe with the --chromedriver-path option"

I'm not sure what to do here, and struggling to find any useful information.  Anyone know how I can get this to work?

```
name: CI Tests
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  axe:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      WORDPRESS_API_URL: XYZ
      GITHUB_API_SECRET: ABC
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 18.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
      - run: yarn install
      - run: yarn run build
      - run: yarn dev & npx wait-on http://localhost:3000
      - name: Run axe
        run: |
          yarn add @axe-core/cli
          npx axe http://localhost:3000  --exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Steven Lambert for pointing me in the right direction. With a bit of trial and error, I ended up with this, which is working:

```
name: CI Tests
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  axe:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      WORDPRESS_API_URL: MY_WORDPRESS_API_URL
      GITHUB_API_SECRET: MY_GITHUB_API_SECRET
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 18.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
      - run: yarn install
      - name: Get Chromium version 
        run: |
          CHROMIUM_VERSION=$(wget -qO- https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE | cut -d. -f1)
          echo "Chromium version: $CHROMIUM_VERSION"
          echo "CHROMIUM_VERSION=$CHROMIUM_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Setup Chrome 
        id: setup-chrome
        uses: browser-actions/setup-chrome@v1
        with:
          chrome-version: ${{ env.CHROMIUM_VERSION }}
      - name: Install chromedriver 
        run: |
          echo "Installing chromedriver version: $CHROMIUM_VERSION"
          yarn add chromedriver@$CHROMIUM_VERSION
          echo "chromedriver version: $(chromedriver --version)"
      - run: yarn run build
      - run: yarn dev & npx wait-on http://localhost:3000
      - name: Run axe
        run: |
          yarn add @axe-core/cli
          CHROMIUM_VERSION=$(google-chrome --version | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d'.' -f1)
          yarn add chromedriver@$CHROMIUM_VERSION
          npx axe --chromedriver-path $(yarn bin)/chromedriver http://localhost:3000/ --load-delay=1500 --exit
```

Answer (score 1):

`@axe-core/cli` uses chromedriver under the hood to open the desired page and run axe. Using chromedriver requires that it uses a version of Chrome that is the same or close to the same with it's own version. When it's not it throws that error.

There's a few different ways to fix the issue. You could [install a chrome and chromedriver version in the action](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core-npm/issues/401#issuecomment-1917605607) that are the same version and location as `@axe-core/cli`. Alternatively you could install chromedriver at any location and pass the location to `@axe-core/cli` using the `--chromedriver-path`  option (as the error message suggests).